# add new fields to existing table

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm sure there is such question at stackoverflow, but i just c't find it :(

I have 2 databases with same data ("developer" database and "production" database). 
"production" database is "Live" database - sitve visitors see this data
"developer" database is database where i create new functions at my local server.

I have situation when i add to "developer" database some new tables and some new fields in old tables.

And now i have to copy this new created fields and tables to "production" database (but only structure, data should not be copied and no data at "production" database must be changed).

UPD: Maybe there is solution where i can make database structure dump from developing database and when i import it to production database, it automatically add all new fields from all tables

What functions should i use?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't see a problem. Save the DDL scripts that were used to update the developer DB and use them on the production DB. That is, if you do use DDL commands (as opposed to making changes interactively, using some tool with a nice UI). If you do not, well, maybe it's time you did. :)

Answer (score 2):

You want `alter table`: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: It appears he also wants create table

Comment: but with this function i have to specify all the fields by myself. maybe there is solution where i can make database structure dump and when i import it to production database, it automatically add all new fields from all tables

Comment: Then you want `mysqldump`, which can dump out a db's structure + data as SQL statements you can feed back in as "real" queries.

Comment: i d't need my test data from developer db, i need only structure from it. and it'll be cool to import this structure (not data) to production database and structure of production database become the same as at developer (not data, only structure). Or i just misunderstand your post :(

Comment: mysqldump can dump just the structure. `--skip-data` or somwething like that (don't have CLI access to it at the moment, but do `mysqldump --help` to see all the options)

Answer (score 1):

To [alter an existing table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html):

```
alter table tablename add column newcolumn tinyint(1) default 1 AFTER othercolumn
```

To [create a new table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE TABLE  `newtablename` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `newcolumn` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

- to copy ONLY the structure you can use like:

  `jcho360> create table t3 like t2`;

  `Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)`.

If you want to copy the content after create the structure you can use :

```
INSERT INTO t3 SELECT * FROM t2;
```

- if you want to copy with data you can use (without structure, I mean, PK, FK, etc)

  `mysql> create table t4 as select * from t1`;

of course you are able to use backup to restore tables too

- if you want to add new column you can use

  `alter table tablename add column newcolumn vartype`;

if you want to use a table from another database you can use queries calling first the database and later the name, like

```
select * from database.tablename;
```

remember the user need permission to the other db too.

Comment: create table t3 like t2 - this query is ok, but i already have table t3 - i d't need to create it, i just need to modify it's fields that they becomes the same as in t2 (but all data remains untouched). i can do this by hands, specifying all the fields by myself, but it takes too lot time and i need to do this automatically.

Comment: if you don't want to hardcoding the best way is with some software with interface, like mysql Administration or workbench, with those you'll be able to do anything over the tables. remember to make a backup before start editing.